# i am fetching data and i am getting weird errors and i cant find the bug in it

Tags: reactjs

i am fetching data and i am getting weird errors and i cant find the bug in it.
I tried every possible way can anyone help me

MultipleReturns.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.usestate) is not a function or its return value is not iterable

```
import React, { usestate, useEffect } from "react";

const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

const MultipleReturns = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = usestate(true);
  const [isError, setIsError] = usestate(false);
  const [user, setUser] = usestate("Default user");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((resp) => {
        resp.json();
      })
      .then((user) => {
        const { login } = user;
        setUser(login);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setIsError(err);
      });
  });
  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>....Loading</h4>
      </div>
    );
  }

  if (isError) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>....Error</h4>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>MultipleReturns</div>
      <h4>{user}</h4>
    </>
  );
};

export default MultipleReturns;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a case of spelling, the state hook is called `useState` not `usestate`